# Deploying GWT in localhost and see that webpage

Tags: gwt

I am a new user in GWT and I want to deploy one of existed samples in my localhost. I could run the example by eclipse and get the result. But I need to deploy that example in my localhost (IIS). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of your project's `war` directory to your server's document root. You could create a folder there, mproject for example. Then load your project on a web browser: `localhost/mproject` to view.

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work! the page with this title is appeared, "Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"". do you know what the problem is?

Comment: sorry, i don't know anything about iis. i'm using apache server. maybe you could try [this step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280137/How-To-Deploy-a-Web-App-in-IIS) to deploy your project.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your project's war directory For EX:
C:\workspace\HelloWorld\war

Select all the files & folders available inside war directory.

Zip all the selected files & folders in a file called HelloWorld.zip.

Rename HelloWorld.zip to HelloWorld.war.

Deploy it to the server

Comment: Go to this link and see the steps for deploying your apps to server        http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_deploy_application.htm